# Count number of bits from data.

Tags: java

actually I am working on Java based Healthcare application. My java application must connect with Healthcare sensor device with the help of Bluetooth. This sensor module done by some other people , We transfer data using DatagramPacket. even I don't know what format of data they are send to me. so now I want to know, how can I find, whether the incoming data are 8-bit data or 16-bit data. and also I want to know how many bits are there , means I want to count the bits. kindly some one help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should find out (probably by asking people) what is the protocol of your sensor. Guessing it takes a lot of time (it is called reverse-engineering). Try to interact with the device supplier.

Comment: Nice to know that people in the healthcare industry have their documents in place ;)

Comment: May be The API and protocols have been defined by your sensor API provider. You need to ask them for proper documentataion..

Comment: oh thank you for your reply friends. I will ask them. other than this , can't I get any other solutions ?